# PHP- how to implement "don't save login" feature

Tags: php, session-cookies

It's a common feature on an authentification page to set flag "Remember me" or "Don't remember me".
Ok, I have a session started for one year with user_id stored there. But if the user chooses to not remember him, and my usual session (+1 year) already started in the start-up section of my framework  - how can I change it to a temporary one, that will be destroyed on browser close?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why i can not delete cookie using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151411/why-i-can-not-delete-cookie-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

to destroy cookies after browser closed or tab close use in page .php :

```
if(isset($_POST['button_dontRemamberMe'])){
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
}
```

**Note:** all cookies in browser for this page will lost