# PHP session destroy is not working properly

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies, session-state

I have a user login which is only valid for 1 hour. I mean the user can login to the system and he can keep doing his works. I am not gonna check the inactive time. I start the calculation from the very beginning of the process where user successfully logged in.Whatever the user doing, I will cache the actions and destroy the session and direct to the log in section for each and every 1 hour after the log in.

When user successfully logged in, i set the timestamp to a `$_SESSION` variable in following manner.
`$_SESSION['key_set_time'] = time();`.

The following is the **SESSION DESTROY** code.

```
$_SESSION['key_set_time'] = time();
$session_duration = 3600;
$current_time = time();
if(((time() - $_SESSION['key_set_time']) > $session_duration)){
    session_destroy();
}else{
    header('LOCATION:/login.php');
}
```

While debugging I found out that `$_SESSION['key_set_time'] = time();` sets the current time in each every page reload.It replaces the time when the user logged in.So I am unable to **DESTROY** the session. How can I prevent the replacing the time in every page reload?
( This process has to be done in the **BACKEND ITSELF**. This noob note is because of a stackoverflow answer which is to destroy the **SESSION MANUALLY**.)

Comment: $_SESSION['key_set_time'] =  empty($_SESSION['key_set_time'] ) ?  time() : $_SESSION['key_set_time'];

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948230/best-way-to-completely-destroy-a-session-even-if-the-browser-is-not-closed) helps

Comment: This sounds good. But still it's returning the current timestamp in page refresh. Is this is done by browser cookie? I have no idea how this is happening.

Comment: @EmptyBrain It didn't help. It resets the session in each and every reload.

Comment: put it in a function. call whenever you want to destroy.

Comment: @EmptyBrain In  my case I have to call it in the header. So it's definitely recalled when a page refreshed

Comment: Just somebody explain me is it possible to keep the old session value in each and every page reload. Because I was unable to find out any article about this issue. Every they mentioned about inactive time and blah blah..

Comment: move `$_SESSION['key_set_time'] = time();` below at the bottom of your code. Also, call `session_unset()` in your if statement before `session_destroy()`. Also add a condition in if `isset($_SESSION['key_set_time'])` - worth a short

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to modify a cookie (like timeout) which is sent via PHP session  - the PHPSESSID thingy

Comment: @kenzotenma How could it be possible to set the `$_SESSION['key_set_time'] = time();` at the end. Because my login form is a part of the header. It is displayed on each and every page. When user logged in i do something and if not there another process. Also my header and footer are separate php files.

Comment: by end I mean where your else statement ends

Comment: @kenzotenma I used `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);` and `session_set_cookie_params(3600);` at the very beginning.Then only I realized it won't help all the time, sometimes it returns some bugs.

Comment: @kenzotenma That's how the current code exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['key_set_time'])) {
$_SESSION['key_set_time'] = time();
} else if (time() - $_SESSION['key_set_time'] > 3600) {
   // session started more than 1 hour ago
   session_regenerate_id(true);    // change session ID for the current session
   $_SESSION['key_set_time'] = time();  // update creation time
}
```

This should work for your case. let me know if it doesn't.

You can alter `else if` statement as per your needs

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: Almost I wasted around two weaks for this few lines.