# unset(session) and session_destroy() not working in PHP5

Tags: php, session

I am new to PHP world. Currently, it's version is 5.

I'm trying to prepare a logout script.

I tried-

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["abc"]);
session_destroy();
```

But still the session vars are alive. I also tried from [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}
session_destroy();
```

Unfortunately, it's not working too.

Any help?

> NOTE I already tried that and I mentioned that code in my question. So
>   it's not a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to completely destroy a session - even if the browser is not closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948230/best-way-to-completely-destroy-a-session-even-if-the-browser-is-not-closed)

Comment: @GianfrancescoAurecchia- have you looked at my question? I already tried that solution in my question.

Comment: What value of ```$_SESSION["abc"]``` is showing just after distroying session...?

Comment: @vaku the value I stored in it.

Comment: see this https://rextester.com/NUMBN89037 
you can try the unser to session after closing